# How can I get the privacy policy page?

Tags: permalinks, privacy

After the update regarding the GDPR, WordPress now has an option named *"Privacy Policy"* under the settings, which you can use a page to be used as your privacy policy page.

How can I get the ID or the permalink for this page to use in my theme or plugin?

Answer (score 15):

WordPress stores the page id for the privacy policy page in the `options` table. To get the value, you can use:

```
$privacy_policy_page = get_option( 'wp_page_for_privacy_policy' );

if( $privacy_policy_page ) {
    $permalink = esc_url( get_permalink( $privacy_policy_page ) );
}
```

The `$privacy_policy_page` variable holds the ID of the privacy policy page.

Comment: You would use:
`if( get_the_ID() == $privacy_policy_page ) { // do something }`

Answer (score 14):

These functions are available since 4.9.6 for the *privacy policy* url and link:

- `get_privacy_policy_url`() - filterable with the `privacy_policy_url` filter.
- `get_the_privacy_policy_link()` - filterable with the `the_privacy_policy_link` filter.
- `the_privacy_policy_link()` - wrapper that outputs `get_the_privacy_policy_link()`.

See ticket [#43850](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43850)